# How to import and export settings from live customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

How many WordPress developer are working with live customizer for controlling theme settings? Do you people allow users to import and export theme settings? Any examples or tutorials would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export/import theme customizer settings?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99472/how-to-export-import-theme-customizer-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently built this for one of my themes...
Export: https://github.com/wpmu/maera/blob/7492f7b90544c792a3eb752d8552674882e1c1cd/lib/admin-page.php#L105-L117
Import: https://github.com/wpmu/maera/blob/7492f7b90544c792a3eb752d8552674882e1c1cd/lib/admin-page.php#L124

That file actually contains an entire admin page with the export data and import textarea so you could simply get that and modify it to suit your own needs.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into it to implement in my theme.