# Migrations for plugins, page and theme: looking for a good approach

Tags: plugins, migration

What are good practices / best plugins / your personal approach for Migrations?

No matter the plugin, always always when I migrate a Wordpress website something goes wrong.
Either links not working, pages not displaying, plugins not installed, forms built with plugins not imported, it never happened to me to have a smooth and flawless transition.

What is a good approach for it? I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or I am missing pieces.

I personally use:

- All-in-One WP migrate => I compile the package and then I import it in the new website
- Since this plugin misses some pieces here and there, I also do a query to substitute the GUID of the pages with the new website migrated
- General Theme files. Some images are not displaying, I wonder if I need to fix some links as well in the DB.

I thanks you in advance for all the suggestions and /or tutorial you can advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339882/how-to-deploy-a-new-theme-theme-options-from-staging-to-production-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best plugin experience I've had is with [WP Migrate DB](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) Pro. I've used a few others, including All-in-One, but this gave the best results and the most control, even allowing you to set up and save regularly used paths between sites for migrations between live, dev, stage environments, etc. It does media migrations, individual tables, and it gives you a clear report of what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Ok thanks :). What about the content itself though? Should I just zip and extract the content folder to a new location or do you use a plugin as well?

Comment: Right, so you install the plugin on your current site, then you create a blank WP install on your new location and install the plugin there as well. Then you can connect them to each other (it's pretty simple in the settings) and you can push from current to new, or pull from current to new. It'll move EVERYTHING for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried already and it worked good ;)! Some settings are still not matching with the old sites but I guess it's templates problems.